# PIP fail to uninstall in venv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I have used a venv created by Pycharm to work on my project

```
(venv) ouyangyikangdeMacBook-Pro:CoppeliaSim_Edu_V4_1_0_Mac ouyangyikang$ which pip
/Users/ouyangyikang/Downloads/CoppeliaSim_Edu_V4_1_0_Mac/venv/bin/pip
```

Then when I tried to uninstall gym, it fails

```
(venv) ouyangyikangdeMacBook-Pro:CoppeliaSim_Edu_V4_1_0_Mac ouyangyikang$ pip uninstall gym
Found existing installation: gym 0.18.0
Not uninstalling gym at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages, outside environment /Users/ouyangyikang/Downloads/CoppeliaSim_Edu_V4_1_0_Mac/venv
Can't uninstall 'gym'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

I'm pretty sure that the pip and python interpreter is working in the venv, but I don't know why I cannot uninstall a package in it.

Any helpful information would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: sounds like you have a `--system-site-packages` virtualenv

Comment: Oh that's true, I can manage the packages I just installed in the venv, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try exiting the venv using "exit" and then uninstalling. Looks like you installed gym outside venv, and hence pip is unable to uninstall from within venv.